# Partitions of 13 and 14 into either four or five smaller integers

Tags: integer-partitions

There are exactly 18 partitions of the integer 13 into 4 parts, as on the left of the table, and also 18 partitions into 5 parts, as on the right of the table:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
10+1+1+1 & 9+1+1+1+1 \\
9+2+1+1 &  8+2+1+1+1 \\
8+3+1+1 &  7+3+1+1+1 \\
8+2+2+1 &  7+2+2+1+1 \\
7+4+1+1 &  6+4+1+1+1\\
7+3+2+1 &  6+3+2+1+1\\
7+2+2+2 &  6+2+2+1+1\\
6+5+1+1 &  5+5+1+1+1\\
6+4+2+1 &  5+4+2+1+1\\
6+3+3+1 &  5+3+3+1+1\\
6+3+2+2 &  5+3+2+2+1\\
5+5+2+1 &  5+2+2+2+2\\
5+4+3+1 &  4+4+3+1+1\\
5+4+2+2 &  4+4+2+2+1\\
5+3+3+2 &  4+3+3+2+1\\
4+4+4+1 &  4+3+2+2+2\\
4+4+3+2 &  3+3+3+3+1\\
4+3+3+3 &  3+3+3+2+2
\end{array}$$

Is there some reason, such as a natural bijection, that one might have expected there to be the same number of partitions of 13 into either 4 or 5 parts?  Or is it a mere coincidence, the Law of Small Numbers at work?

Finding a bijection is of course trivial, but I have not been able to find one that seems to respect the structure of the partitions. The most natural sort of bijection would be a member of an infinite family of such bijections.

Or perhaps there is an explanation of this sort: “So-and-so's theorem states that under certain conditions $p(n, k) = c\cdot p(n, f(k))$, and as it happens this is the single case of so-and-so's theorem where $c=1$.”

Similarly, there are 23 partitions of 14 into 4 parts, and also 23 partitions of 14 into 5 parts. Coincidence, or is there something interesting going on?

Comment: 13 is a prime and 14 is in the form pq for p,q prime. Have you noticed this to some other random number not prime and not of some specific form as 14?

Comment: Isn't every number of some specific form such as $p$, $pq$, $pq+1$, $p^2q$, etc.? Is there any reason to believe this occurrence is related to the primeness of 13 or the $pq$-ness of 14?

Comment: It's possible that it would be fruitful to look at this not as dividing 13 into 4 parts each $\geq$ 1 but as dividing 9 into 4 parts each $\geq$ 0, or counting the distinct ways of putting 9 items in 4 buckets. Nothing leapt out at me when I tried it (why are there the same number of ways to put 9 items in 4 buckets as 8 items in 5 buckets?) but it may enable the use of other tools in your toolbox.

Comment: No I have no clue if this is related to the specific form of 13 or 14. I was just curious whether you noticed this to occur in numbers    whose prime factorization is not $p$ or $pq$ or $p^2q$ or $p_1^1p_2^1...p_k^1$. Maybe this occurrence is related to the form of the prime factorization.

Comment: Further such coincidences might include: $p(34, 4) = p(34,17) = 297$; $p(43,9) = p(43,11)=5708$; $p(60,4) = p(60,36) = 1575$, after which I find nothing of interest for $n\le 200$.

Comment: I vote for coincidence. Why 4/5 parts and not 2/3 or 3/4 parts, for example?

Comment: There are also examples with 2/3 and 3/4: $p(5,2) = p(5,3)$ and $p(6,2) = p(6,3)$, and $p(8,3) = p(8,4)$. I didn't consider them surprising enough or interesting enough to mention, but I suppose they might be related.